# Mono/Linux character encoding issue?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mono

I am working on a project that runs as a .NET console application. I originally wrote this in Windows, but I just converted to GNU/Linux and installed Mono, which runs my application just fine, however there is a problem with the output.

[image]

The output should read something like 'Loading plugin '/blabla/bla/path'
but as you can see there is, well.... Giberish

I am pretty sure that there is some sort of escape sequence that is causing this, but I can not thing of what. Any one know what could be causing this mess?

Comment: Without seeing any source code, one can only speculate, as you have, that there is some encoding issue.

Comment: It echoes out , forexample [Info] 0:34  bla bla bla. That is the part that causes this, but I don't know why....

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out! This is caused by changing the Console.Forecolor or back color.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's either a bug in mono, or in your Linux distro. Look over here:

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/TermInfoDriver.cs#L149

Now look at what your $TERM looks like - chances are its contents isn't 'xterm' but something like 'xterm-256color'. You will notice that it falls through. What happens there exactly, i don't know, but i don't think it's falling through to ANSI terminal, as that should also work, but rather picks up a terminfo file from your distro that it chokes upon and emits invalid escape sequences for colour markup.  Also you will probably notice that once you set your $TERM to be something it recognizes, all the colours are gonna be shiny and work awesomely.